# How do I search for unread mails with specific Google+ Circle in my Gmail?

Tags: gmail, search, google-plus

I want to search for unread mails but with specific circle.

Is it possible or I've to press next => next page and have to look it manually to find unread emails under specific Google+ circle - as Google+ is now integrated with Gmail?

Answer (score 2):

Gmail currently does not support an advanced search to let you combine an unread filter with a circle filter.

I would imagine *if and only if* there was such a filter it would like

```
[ circle:Friends is:unread ]
```

But there is no such filter unfortunately.

Comment: Its not working as Gmail doesn't support Circle filter tag yet !

Comment: That's what I said. "Gmail currently does not support".

Comment: -1 no need for a figurative example that doesn't work

Comment: My answer, that what the OP wants is not possible, is a factual and helpful answer to the question. If I go on to speculate about what the solution will eventually look like, don't let that distract you.

Answer (score 0):

I've observed today that Google has added this feature, so common `operators` are working along with `circle` syntax while searching mails.

Comment: Are they rolling it out? I'm not seeing it. `circle:frieds` works, and `is:unread` works, but when I combine the two into `circle:friends is:unread` I get 0 results back.

Answer (score -1):

just disable the lab "App Search" and clause circle:XXX will work along with is:unread and other search clauses.

Comment: Might you be able to add a screenshot of what this would look like?